# Pigeon Maps Marker Issue

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to integrate a map in react specifically pigeon-maps since it is an open source.But,I am not able to get the co-ordinates from the map.Can anyone give me some code examples.I have set markers and overlay.I am able to center the map but have no idea how to get the latitude and longitude from the map.

Below is the code for the mapcomponent I am trying to create

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./mapcomponent.module.css";
import Marker from "pigeon-marker";
import Map from "pigeon-maps";
import Overlay from "pigeon-overlay";

class MapComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { lat: null, long: null };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        lat: Number(this.props.lat),
        long: Number(this.props.long)
      },
      () => {
        console.log("HERE", this.state.lat, this.state.long);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container} width="500px" height="500px">
        <Map center={[this.state.lat, this.state.long]} zoom={12}>
          <Marker anchor={[this.state.lat, this.state.long]} payload={1} />
          <Overlay
            anchor={[this.state.lat, this.state.long]}
            offset={[120, 79]}
          >
            <img src="pigeon.jpg" width={240} height={158} alt="" />
          </Overlay>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MapComponent;
```

Can anyone help me to and extend marker and manipulate its value

Answer (score 1):

We have to provide the latitude and longitude to plot the marker on map or you can get latitude and longitude from the map events (like onclick)

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: You can find example https://pigeon-maps.js.org/. And you can get related doccumentation  https://github.com/mariusandra/pigeon-maps